# Phusion passanger, apache, dojo and css font-face urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, dojo, font-face, passenger

I deploy my application using phusion passanger on apache web server.
I'm using dojo boilerplate project for js/css minification.
In production, i see errors like:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/dojo/dist/app/resources/design/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot)%20format(\"eot\"),%20url(design/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff)%20format(\"woff\"),%20url(design/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf)%20format(\"truetype\"),%20url(design/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg)%20format(\"svg\""):
```

I have the files in my dist directory, but can't understand why the browser asks for

```
"/dojo/dist/app/resources/design/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot)%20format(\"eot\"),%20url(design/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff)%20format(\"woff\"),%20url(design/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf)%20format(\"truetype\"),%20url(design/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg)%20format(\"svg\""
```

instead of

```
"/dojo/dist/app/resources/design/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot"
```

my css looks pretty normal:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url("design/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot");

  src: url("design/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot") format('eot'), url("design/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff") format('woff'), url("design/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'), url("design/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

EDIT:
Apparently it has something to do with clients using older internet explorer, and not the deployment environment.

Here is the link providing some light on the matter:

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/04/05/lessons-on-font-face-from-the-f2e-summit/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it has something to do with clients using older internet explorer, and not the deployment environment.

Here is the link providing some light on the matter:

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/04/05/lessons-on-font-face-from-the-f2e-summit/